# separador de miles en input javascript asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, mvc, formularios

espero y  me puedan ayudar, quiero un separador de miles que  guarde el monto que corresponde, tengo el sgte codigo

```
  <script>

        $("#txtValC").on({
            "focus": function (event) {
                $(event.target).select();
            },
            "keyup": function (event) {
                $(event.target).val(function (index, value) {
                    return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                        .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
                        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

En teoria funciona bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de guardar a la base de datos, solo me guarda el valor antes de la coma (,) y sucede lo mismo cuando traigo al formulario que tengo:
en SQL (No hacer casos a los valores nulos, que esta hecho a proposito, el valor que ingrese es el ultimo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi formulario cuando traigo los datos:
solamete me trae el valor despues de la coma (,):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda que de acuerdo a la región y formato (UTF, ISO) el formato de números varía, para tí está claro que el punto es mil y la coma es decimal, pero en otros formatos, la coma es mil y el punto decimal.

Comment: @Jean Gotopo Bueno no tome en cuenta eso, lo siento, pero de todas formas creo que se entiende lo que quiero hacer, no me interesa si es por punto o coma en si, si no la separacion que sean en miles.

Comment: @Jean Gotopo aclaro que ese codigo lo saque de aqui mismo de Stackoverflow, me sirvio, pero me di cuenta de ese error al guardar

Comment: Es que por la imagen que pones, es lo que está pasando, para el lenguaje que usas 1.000 es uno con tres decimales como cero, y por eso lo coloca como 1. Y si lo sacaste de Stackoverflow, y le funcionó al otro, es por lo que te digo de la región.

Comment: @Jean Gotopo Entonces en donde esta el punto deberia colocar la coma?, acabo de hacer eso, y nada, solamente me guarda hasta 3 digitos despues un punto o coma

Comment: Aunque representes el número correctamente en JavaScript/html, la base de datos es otro tema. Seguramente tengas que transformarlo para que se inserte correctamente. Para no lidiar con estos problemas es mejor manejar un formato interno usando punto para decimales y nada para miles, y otro formato para mostrar. De esa manera la única transformación es al mostrar el número, pero todos los cálculos y todas las inserciones mantienen un único formato.

Comment: @ Emeeus Tuvieras algun ejemplo practico?